# Inheriting NSDecimalNumber

Tags: objective-c, class, inheritance, extend, nsdecimalnumber

I am trying to create Price class that extends NSDecimalNumber but when trying to alloc it and init it is raising exceptions. Any idea what can be a problem?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Did you forget to nest alloc and initWithString: ?'
```

Price.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Price : NSDecimalNumber
+ (Price*)priceWithString:(NSString*)val;
@end
```

Price.m

```
#import "Price.h"

@implementation Price
- (NSString *)description {
    return [[super description] stringByAppendingString:@" €"];
}
+ (Price*)priceWithString:(NSString*)val {
    return [[Price alloc] initWithString:val];
}
@end
```

Edit:
Even bare class is not working. If I am extending NSDecimalNumber and then trying to do alloc init, the same exception. I gave up at this...

Comment: Should use `instancetype`/`self`.

Comment: Where is your `initWithString:` method in the `Price` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSDecimalNumber` inherits `NSNumber`, which is a [*class cluster*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH4). This makes it very tough to inherit `NSDecimalNumber`, because there is a number of additional requirements for such inheriting. According to Apple documentation, your class needs to

> - Be a subclass of the cluster’s abstract superclass
> - Declare its own storage
> - Override all initializer methods of the superclass
> - Override the superclass’s primitive methods (described below)

In your case, your `Price` class would need to re-implement a lot of `NSDecimalNumber`, which is probably too much work.

A better approach would be to nest `NSDecimalNumber` inside your `Price` class, and add a method to obtain its numeric value, like this:

```
@interface Price : NSObject

/// Represents the numeric value of the price
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDecimalNumber *valueInLocalCurrency;

/// Represents the pricing currency
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *currencyCode;

/// Creates an immutable Price object
-(id)initWithPriceInLocalCurrency:(NSDecimalNumber*)price andCurrencyCode:(NSString*)currencyCode;

@end
```

Once consequence of this decision is that you can no longer send a `Price` object to places where an `NSDecimalNumber` object is expected. This has a potential of preventing silly errors when you disregard the currency by mistake, so it is probably a good safety measure.

Comment: `return [super initWithString:str];`?  Unless of course he needs some custom initialization.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. The default implementation would be called if he didn't override it.

Comment: I'm wrong, you're correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963078/objective-c-did-you-forget-to-nest-alloc-and-init

Comment: @nhgrif I think you need to assign `self` in the designated initializer. You can fold it in a single line, `return self=[super initWithString:str];` but I think the assignment needs to be there.

Comment: Again but on different line
    
    - (id)initWithString:(NSString*)value {
        return self=[super initWithString:value];
    }

I dont know what is going on...

Comment: @MichałHernas I think I know what's going on. Please see the edit.

Comment: Thanks you very much! :) I did what u told before, I was just curious why it is not working and wanted to learn.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: "I think you need to assign self in the designated initializer." Nope. It is meaningless to assign to a local variable (`self`) just to return it.

Comment: @newacct Thanks, that is nice to know! I never got clarity on it from reading various books and articles on Objective C.